# Strange Struct Array Printing Error in C

Tags: c, pointers, struct, parameter-passing, pointer-arithmetic

Hey all I'm having some trouble diagnosing the reason for an error in printing an array of structures in C.

In a separate header file (call it `header.h`) I have the following typedef'd structure:

```
typedef struct instruction prog;

struct instruction{
char kind;
char op[4];
};
```

For my main programing task I want to read from a file a series of what are supposed to be instructions consisting of a type character (the variable `kind` above) and an instruction consisting of four integers (listed as `op` above). Examples include `R 1004` `E 1008`, etc. I can read the data in just fine but it seems to be storing things improperly. I wrote the following test code to see if I could find the error but I was still getting the same issue. My goal is to store these as an array of instructions where, using the parlance of the code below, `mem[i].kind = 'R'` and `mem[i].op =`1004`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include "header.h"

void memFill(prog *P, int x);
void memPrint(prog *P, int x);

int main(){
    prog mem[10];

    memFill(&mem[0], 10);
    memPrint(&mem[0], 10);
return 0;
}


void memFill(prog *P, int x){
char *v = "1004";
for(int i = 0; i< x; i++){
    P->kind = 'R';
    strcpy(P->op, v);
    P++;
}
}


void memPrint(prog *P, int x){
for(int i = 0; i <x; i++){
    printf("%c %s\n",P->kind, P->op);
    P++;
}
}
```

This is giving me output that looks like this:

```
R 1004R1004R1004R1004R1004R1004R1004R1004R1004R1004
R 1004R1004R1004R1004R1004R1004R1004R1004R1004
R 1004R1004R1004R1004R1004R1004R1004R1004
R 1004R1004R1004R1004R1004R1004R1004
R 1004R1004R1004R1004R1004R1004
R 1004R1004R1004R1004R1004
R 1004R1004R1004R1004
R 1004R1004R1004
R 1004R1004
R 1004
```

The reason this is weird is that identical pointer arithmetic has given just fine results with a similar structure. What's going on here? What am I missing?

Comment: Thanks to @LPs for the good answer!

Comment: Also @Frankie_C your post was equally helpful. Both of you helped me avoid another bug in my profile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to give space for the string ending null.
Fix your struct declaration to this:

```
struct instruction{
char kind;
char op[5];
};
```

And it will work.
You can also simplify declaration this way:

```
typedef struct instruction{
char kind;
char op[5];
} prog;
```

Answer (score 1):

Buffer overflow on `char op[4]`, then [Undefined_behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior)

To be able to store `"1004"` it have to be `5 bytes long` to have space for `NULL` terminator.

```
struct instruction{
char kind;
char op[5];
};
```

Literal string `"1004"` is `'1', '0', '0', '4', '\0'`